# How to get the updated json ater each event in jquery form builder

Tags: jquery, forms

I have implemented a form and storing the JSON in a textarea on the event like below:

```
document.addEventListener('fieldAdded', function() {
  document.getElementById('data1').value = formBuilder.formData;    
});
```

When I am editing the form if I remove one field or edit one field or copy one field I am unable to get the event. So what are those events or how can I get the updated JSON so I can show it in the textarea after anything changes in the form without any clicks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `fieldAdded` is not a standard DOM event. Is it part of a third party library you're using?

Comment: i am using  https://formbuilder.online/

Answer (score 0):

I share with you what I was able to found out. I know is old, but maybe can help someone else to save some hour.

Digging into the code I've found next events:

- fieldAdded
- viewData
- userDeclined
- modalClosed
- modalOpened
- formSaved
- fieldRemoved
- fieldRendered
- fieldEditOpened
- fieldEditClosed

Unfortunately, once I thought the 'formSaved' was the right event to get always the last instance, I realize that the event is not arise in all changes.

So my final solution, which it works in a form, is to listen for the event 'submit' and take the formData in that moment.

I hope that can help you in some direction.

Tested in jQuery formBuilder Version 3.6.1